# failed to load elasticseach nodes

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster

Recently, I began to learn jhipster. After I have biuld a jhipster project and run it ,but it throws a error :

```
 ERROR 16725 --- [  restartedMain] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{yaU7NNKDRzK_pZir0MCKNw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

and here is my elasticsearch.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    cmpmanager-elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:5.6.5
        # volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/CMPManager/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300
        command: -Enetwork.host=0.0.0.0 -Ediscovery.type=single-node
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are access the ES nodes from another host check the node status using below command,

```
curl '192.168.x.y:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

If it failed to show status, you have to open ES to access via public.

```
host=0.0.0.0
```

Not works for me also.